# Prevent Login Redirect on 403 When an Ajax Call

Tags: sxa, authentication, webapi, error-handling

Using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8

Does anyone know the best way to force Sitecore to return a legit `403` error when an Ajax call is hitting an `API` method?

Currently when the following code is thrown within the `API` method, Sitecore is redirecting to the `/login` page - so the Ajax call is getting the raw HTML of the login page sent to it with a `200` status instead of a `403` status.

```
throw new WebException("Invalid Credentials", WebExceptionStatus.RequestProhibitedByProxy);
```

Answer (score 1):

## First Approach(Recommended)

If you want to make ***centralizer*** `authentication/authorization` logic for any API methods then implement `authentication/authorization` filter, Here below sample example we are implementing custom authorization filter.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// CustomAuthorizationAttribute
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute" />
    public class CustomAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
       public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
         // Here your core logic
       }       

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the unauthorized request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext">The filter context.</param>
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            //set unauthorized(401) response
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult(); 
        }
    }
```

## Second Approach

As per your query, you can check response content-type using global `ajaxComplete` method.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {    
    try {
        //html response and login page. 
        if (request.getResponseHeader("content-type").indexOf('html') > -1)
            //write custom logic
    }
    catch (e) {
        
    }
});
```